# Search Informations on BioShock

Tags: bioshock

Is there a way / place where you can review the tips that we are shown throughout the game? For example, when I do research with the camera, he mentioned such as "Vulnerable to anti-personnel munitions and heat. "

Do I have to remember all that, or I am able to review all this information to a specific location?

I did my research through the menu and the help, but nothing conclusive about my assailants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bioshock 1 you can't view the result of your researches (at least in the pc version). In Bioshock 2 there is a seperate tab in the game menu (if oyu open the map, etc.).

If you searching for information you can have a look onto: http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/931329-bioshock/faqs/50039